# What is the general term for projecting binary images onto axes?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

When you have a binary image, you can characterize the image by "projecting" onto the x- and/or y-axis to produce histograms. This can also be done onto lines in any direction, not just vertical or horizontal. What is the general term for this technique?

Theoretically, if you project onto lines forming a complete circle around the image, you can bound some binary object perfectly.

(I found it once, but have forgotten and can't find it anymore)

In MATLAB this is as simple as performing `sum(mat, 1)` or `sum(mat,2)` for the horizontal and vertical projections.

Answer (score 1):

I know it as "Projection Histograms", but I found it as "Projection functions" in this paper: Zhi-Hua Zhou and Xin Geng, "Projection Functions for Eye Detection", Pattern Recognition 2004:37:5, pp1049--1056.

Answer (score 0):

[Projection slice theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-slice_theorem): this is how CT works.